# Angular 2 transclusion into sibling component

Tags: angular, transclusion

I am struggling to inject content into a sibling component aka sidebar. I have my app.component.html content as follows:

```
<app-header></app-header>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div id="main-menu" class="col-md-1 col-sm-3">
        <app-main-menu></app-main-menu>
    </div>
    <div id="main" class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<app-control-aside></app-control-aside>
```

app-control-aside (simplified):

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#control-sidebar-options-tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#control-sidebar-settings-tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-options-tab">
        <ng-content select="[tab-options-container]"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-settings-tab">
        <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">General Settings</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

My "app-control-aside" contains two tabs and I would like to dynamically load one of the tabs "tab-options-container" with options from the child component of the router-outlet.

Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!